# Induction proof: $2\times6\times10\times ... \times (4n-2) = (2n)!/n!$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, induction

What I'm missing to solve this problem is the algebra steps to prove the inductive step.  The base case is clear: $2 = 2!/1!$.  Suppose it's for true for $k \ge 1$.  Must show it's true for $k + 1$.  Using the hypothesis, we can write

$$2\times6\times10\times14\times18\times ... \times (4k-2) = \frac{(2k)!}{k!}.$$

Now I take the obvious step: I multiply $4(k+1) - 2$ on both sides of the equation and I get

\begin{align*}
2\times6\times10\times14\times18\times ... \times (4k-2) [4(k+1) - 2] = \frac{(2k)!}{k!} 4(k+1) - 2).
\end{align*}

Now my job must be putting the RHS into the form $(2(k+1))!/(k + 1)!$.  But I'm not able to do it.  I look at a special case such as $k = 3$.  I get $14 \times 6!/3!$ and that equals $8!/4!$, but it doesn't seem obvious how to put it in the general case.  I need some algebra help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you need is

$$4(k+1)-2=4k+2=2(2k+1)=\dfrac{2(2k+1)(2k+2)}{2(k+1)}=\dfrac{(2k+1)(2k+2)}{k+1}.$$

Can you take it from here?

Comment: Yes, I can!  Thanks!  That was great.  You just multiplied $4(k+1) -2)$ by $2(k + 1)/2(k + 1)$.  But how in the world did you see it is the mystery.  I guess having a denominator of $(k + 1)$ makes a lot of sense and perhaps it wouldn't be so much of a stretch to have an extra two in the numerator.  But I guess I'm not at the level yet.  Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome.  It may have helped that I knew what I wanted to get to

Comment: I think you easily saw that $(2(k + 1))! = (2k)! (2k + 1) (2k + 2)$.  I didn't!  I had to even check some particular cases to see that it was true and it was a natural thing.  I guess I'm learning a bunch here!